# jQuery/Ajax form automatically submitting even though I have event.preventDefault in the submit action

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, asp.net-core, razor

I have an existing form that uses Ajax and jQuery. I'm trying to prevent it from automatically submitting and I've put event.preventDefault() in the submit action:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
NewRequest.bindShortcuts();

var validator = $("#NewRequest").validate();
validator.resetForm();

$('#NewRequest').submit(function (event) {
    console.log("In $('#NewRequest').submit() - newrequest.js");
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

My intention is to have actions in the $('#btnUpdateRequest').on('click') that check to see if the user really wants to submit (based on a set of criteria, but the form continues to submit automatically. This is the top of the form.

```
        <div class="ibox-content">
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
            @using (Ajax.BeginForm("NewRequest", "Request", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", OnBegin = "OnBegin", OnSuccess = "OnSuccess", OnFailure = "OnFailure" }, new { @class = "form", role = "form", @id = "NewRequest" }))
            {
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button id="btnUpdateRequest" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="shortcut">U</span>pdate Request</button>
                    <span class="text-danger" style="margin-left: 30px;">@TempData["errorMessage"]</span>
                </div>

                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                @Html.Partial("_Questions")
```

I've looked and can't find any other events bound to the click. Why is it automatically submitting?

Answer (score 0):

> I've looked and can't find any other events bound to the click. Why is
> it automatically submitting?

The `submit()` method submits the form (same as clicking the Submit button).The `preventDefault()` method cancels the event if it is cancelable, meaning that the default action that belongs to the event will not occur, like : prevent it from submitting a form.

Try to add use `event.preventDefault();` with below script

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately we're using an older version of jQuery. I actually switched to using Html.BeginForm and that seems to have solved my problem.